# Angular Js: Image Slider not working after scope update

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to show image slide in angular js. When the page loads the images are showing properly. I have a search button (which will be a default string at the starting of the page) when try to search something, the scope disappears. I tried to debug, the search makes a http call which returns the output properly but something wrong with the binding. Can some one tell me what is wrong here ? I tried to add console, it prints correctly with console but not showing in the ui or slides

```
<input class="form-control" style="width: 50%;margin: auto;" type="text" placeholder="Location"
                       no-special-char ng-model="customerLocation"
                       required>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="searchLocation()">Search</button>

<div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <carousel interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
                <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
                    <a href="{{slide.detailPage}}" target="_blank">
                        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="width:300px; height:400px; margin:auto;">
                    </a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption" style="color:black">
                        <p style="background:white">{{slide.text}}</p>
                    </div>
                </slide>
            </carousel>
        </div>
```

JS code :

```
$http.get('/getCurrentLocation.do').success(      
        function (result) {
            var testing = [];
            var index = 1;
            for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var model = result[i];
                var title = {};
                title.id = index;
                title.text = model.title.title;
                title.size = model.count;
                title.image = model.titleImageURL;
                title.detailPage =  model.detailPage;
                title.active = (index == 1 ? true : false);
                index++;
                testing.push(title);
            }
            $scope.slides = testing;   ## works here
        });

    $scope.searchLocation = function() {
        searchForLocation();
    }

    function searchForLocation() {
        if ($scope.customerLocation != null) {

            $http.get('/getSearchLocation.do',
                      {params: {'searchLocation': $scope.customerLocation}}).success(
                        function (result) {
                            var testing = [];
                            var index = 1;
                            for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                                var model = result[i];
                                var title = {};
                                title.id = index;
                                title.text = model.title.title;
                                title.size = model.count;
                                title.image = model.titleImageURL;
                                title.detailPage =  model.detailPage;
                                title.active = (index == 1 ? true : false);
                                index++;
                                testing.push(title);
                            }
                            $scope.slides = testing;   ## not working here though the testing has values
                        });
        }
    }
```

I think somthing with the angular model but couldn't figure out what is the issue here

Comment: @AluanHaddad oh..but it works when I do getCurrentLocation I mean it always works the when I load first but not when I do search

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you are using the deprecated `success` method. The response body is not wrapped in that case.